# Django and Session Status Messages

Tags: django, session

I need to have a status message that is set while processing an initial request appear after a redirect occurs.  A pretty normal thing to need to do but I'm unclear how to use the session object to do this in Django.  I know there's a plugin someone made: https://github.com/danielfm/django-flash/wiki

Is that the recommended way of handling this situation in Django or can something simpler be done with the default install of Django?

Comment: Anyone seeing this question should know that Django 1.2 added the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standardized (in Django) method yet for session messages.

Here's a good discussion of the issues: [Towards a Standard for Django Session Messages](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/06/19/towards-a-standard-for-django-session-messages/)

Besides the django-flash project you already found there is a least one other one: [django-notify](http://code.google.com/p/django-notify/).

Comment: Django 1.2 added the [messages app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: I believe this answer is no longer accurate. See Dave's answer re: django messages.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like this is part of django as of 1.2:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/